# Is there a way to get the last element of a list faster than O(n) in Java?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following code, where `getIDs()` returns a list of IDs:

```
List<Long> ids = getIds();
Long neededID = ids.get(ids.size()-1);
```

Now sonarqube says:

> Collection methods with O(n) performance should be used carefully (java:S2250)
> The time complexity of method calls on collections is not always obvious. For instance, for most collections the size() method takes constant time, but the time required to execute ConcurrentLinkedQueue.size() is O(n), i.e. directly proportional to the number of elements in the collection. When the collection is large, this could therefore be an expensive operation.
> This rule raises an issue when the following O(n) methods are called outside of constructors on class fields:

I did not find any public link to show you that rule.

So in my understanding the rule says `size()` has a runtime of O(n) and I could `get()` an element of the list faster if I would know the last index. So my question is now if there is an way to get the last element of the list faster, without using `size()`.

I have already done some search but the only thing that I found if I search for get last element of list is that you can use `list.get(list.size()-1)`.

Comment: What implementation of List is it?

Comment: "*So in my understanding the rule says size() has a runtime of O(n)*" No. For *some specific collections* it's O(n). For e.g. ArrayList, it's O(1)

Comment: its a LinkedList from java.util.LinkedList.

Comment: LinkedList.size() is O(1).

Comment: Java's `LinkedList` has some optimisations unlike "classic" data structure

Comment: LinkedList also has `getLast` directly, FYI

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that LinkedList does not have getLast.

Comment: `LinkedList` does have a [`getLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#getLast()) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.get(list.size()-1)` would always be O(n) because a linked list is not a random access data structure like a primitive array.  To retrieve a value of a given position in the list, you would have to traverse the list starting at the first node until you get to the node of the position you want.  So, don't use `list.get(index)` to retrieve the last element.  Many implementation maintain a reference to the last node in the list so that retrieving the last element is O(1).  I don't have the code of `java.util.LinkedList` but I would imagine its method `getLast()` is O(1).

Comment: The Sonar rule in question is not (only) about `get(..)`, but also about `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was that a `LinkedList.getSize()` only has a complexity of O(1). So it was not relevant for me.

Comment: Yes, but `LinkedList.get(index)` is O(n). So if you do `list.get(list.size() - 1)` it's still O(n).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Jesper That is not entirely correct, getting the first or last item is O(1), because depending whether the requested index is before or after the midpoint, it will start at the start or end of the list. So for an index of size - 1, it starts at the end, finding the element immediately: O(1).